# push in the Angular not able to produce expected result

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to angular learning the push.

I am using a textbox to add data to the table. and passing it by template reference to component by clicking a button.

In component, I am using the value of the textbox and push function, but I am unable to retrive the data

HTML code

```
<input type="text"  #userName >

<button (click)="addToTable(userName)">Add To Table</button>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let u of users">
            <td>{{u.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ng-if',
  templateUrl: './ng-if.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ng-if.component.css']
})
export class NgIfComponent implements OnInit {

      selectedProduct=[];

      constructor() {
        this.selectedProduct;
      }

      addToTable(userName:any){
        this.selectedProduct.push(
          {name:userName.value}
          );
      }
      ngOnInit() {}
    }
```

Comment: Here you push in selectedProduct and iterate on users, replace users with selectedProduct in html to get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqdyvb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts):

```
export class AppComponent  {
  users = [
    {name: 'shan'}
  ]

  addToTable(data){
    this.users.push(
      {name: data.value}
    )
    data.value = ''
  }

}
```

You need to push value in `users` array and not `selectedProduct`

Comment: Thank you for solution @ Shashank Vivek